# Apps keeps crashing because of syntax error

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

please help me with this problem. My app keeps crashing because of this. What I want to do is to display the user's information from the SQLite database after they login in a text view on the profile activity. Please help me with my project. I'm still new to android studio.

this is the syntax error in my logcat

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "null": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: Select * from USER_TABLE where null=?null =?null =?
```

This is my Database Helper

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    public static String C_EMAIL,C_PREFERENCES,C_PASSWORD;;



    public DatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, constants.DB_NAME, null, constants.DB_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(constants.CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + constants.TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertInfo(String email, String preference,String password) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(constants.C_EMAIL, email);
        values.put(constants.C_PREFERENCES, preference);
        values.put(constants.C_PASSWORD , password);

        long id = db.insert(constants.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        if (id == -1) {
            return false;
        }else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean userExists (String email){
        String [] columns = {C_EMAIL};
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String selection = C_EMAIL + "=?";
        String selectionArgs []= { email };
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME,columns,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        if (count > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

  public Cursor getData(String email, String Password){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery(" Select * from "+ TABLE_NAME + " where "+ C_EMAIL + "=?" + C_PASSWORD + " =?", new String[]{email,Password});
        return res;
    }
}
```

This is my login.java

```
loginacc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Cursor rs = dbHelper.getData(loginemail.getText().toString(),loginpassword.getText().toString());
                if(rs.moveToFirst()){
                    String email = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.C_EMAIL));
                    String preference = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.C_PREFERENCES));
                    String password = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.C_PASSWORD));


                    Toast.makeText(login.this,"Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(login.this,profile.class);
                    intent.putExtra("email", email);
                    intent.putExtra("preference", preference);
                    intent.putExtra("password", password);
                    startActivity(intent);

                    if(rs != null && rs.isClosed()){
                        rs.close();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(login.this,"Invalid Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

This is my profile.java

```
public class profile extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    TextView pemail,ppreferences, ppassword;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        pemail = findViewById(R.id.pemail);

        ppreferences = findViewById(R.id.ppreferences);
        ppassword = findViewById(R.id.ppassword);


        pemail.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("email"));
        ppreferences.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("preferences"));
        ppassword.setText((getIntent().getStringExtra("password")));
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where is the code which generates the SQL code referenced in the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring 3 static variables here:

```
public static String C_EMAIL,C_PREFERENCES,C_PASSWORD;
```

without assigning any value to them so they are all `null`.
When you use them inside `getData()`:

```
" Select * from "+ TABLE_NAME + " where "+ C_EMAIL + "=?" + C_PASSWORD + " =?"
```

the result is:

```
Select * from USER_TABLE where null=?null =?null =?
```

(it's not clear from your code where the 3d `null =?` comes from)
What you want is (I guess) to use these variables for the column names of the table.
So change the declarations to:

```
public static String C_EMAIL = "email"; // change to the actual column name
public static String C_PASSWORD = "password"; // change to the actual column name
public static String C_PREFERENCES = "preferences"; // change to the actual column name
```

Also add the `AND` operator in the sql statement:

```
"Select * from "+ TABLE_NAME + " where "+ C_EMAIL + "= ? AND " + C_PASSWORD + " = ?"
```

Edit
Inside the method `insertInfo()` you use `constants.C_EMAIL`, `constants.C_PREFERENCES` and `constants.C_PASSWORD` which it seems are the names of your columns.
If so, then use them also in the sql statement and drop the static variables:

```
"Select * from "+ TABLE_NAME + " where "+ constants.C_EMAIL + "= ? AND " + constants.C_PASSWORD + " = ?"
```